# Get item of a map <string dynamic> using a var

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get a value from Map<String, dynamic>

like this

```
class UserFields {
  static const String id = 'id';
  static const String name = 'name';
}

final name = data[UserFields.name] as String? ?? ''
```

but I am getting this error

```
CastError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?
```

what I do wrong, I could do that in swift

Comment: what is `data` variable here?

Comment: @Soliev it is Map<String, dynamic>

Comment: I run it on DartPad [link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=b7a4dfa8a808049aa9581a261e9142e4) but see no error as long as `data` is `Map<String, dynamic>`

Comment: @Soliev thanks  you are right 
i found the problem, the type data is not string it List<String>
but it crash